# How to detect event store changes and what is change? From EKEventStoreChangedNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

how to know whether EKEvent is added or deleted? so that i can schedule notification for event. otherwise for deleted event also it will schedule a notification. any help?

```
 -(void)storeChanged:(NSNotification*)notification{

    EKEventStore *ekEventStore = notification.object;

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
    [offsetComponents setDay:0];
    [offsetComponents setMonth:4];
    [offsetComponents setYear:0];
    NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:now options:0];

    NSArray *ekEventStoreChangedObjectIDArray = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"EKEventStoreChangedObjectIDsUserInfoKey"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [ekEventStore    predicateForEventsWithStartDate:now
                                                                      endDate:endDate
                                                                    calendars:nil];
    // Loop through all events in range
    [ekEventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate usingBlock:^(EKEvent *ekEvent, BOOL *stop) {
        // Check this event against each ekObjectID in notification
        [ekEventStoreChangedObjectIDArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *ekEventStoreChangedObjectID, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSObject *ekObjectID = [(NSManagedObject *)ekEvent objectID];
            if ([ekEventStoreChangedObjectID isEqual:ekObjectID]) {
                // Log the event we found and stop (each event should only exist once in store)
                NSLog(@"calendarChanged(): Event Changed: title:%@", ekEvent.title);

                NSLog(@"%@",ekEvent);

                NSInteger total = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]count];
                if (total == 64) {
                    [self cancelLastNotification];
                }

                NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:ekEvent, nil];
                [self scheduleNotificationForCalendarEvents:NO andEvents:newArray];

                *stop = YES;
            }
        }];
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `refresh` property, it will return false when it has been deleted, and true if you can still use it.